# Using AC line as DC neutral reference for a microprocessor

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, integrated-circuit, dc, zener

I've been trying to repair this espresso machine circuit, but am scratching my head as to their **use of the AC mains power seemingly as the DC reference**. Any help would be appreciated.

**In total I have a few questions:**

1. How do they use 120 VAC as the micro ground?
2. How do they use 120 VAC reference as the reference for the Zener diodes ZD6 (24 V Zener), ZD1 (5 V Zener) whilst the Zener diodes still function in their reversed bias direction?
3. How is ZD6 able to keep the voltage at 24 VDC given that it appears to have no resistors between it and the power supplied through D1 & D2 and that it has full 120 VAC as its reference?

[Full Schematic](https://siber-sonic.com/appliance/etc/800ESXL/800ESXLschematic.gif)

[image]

Question 1 reference:

[image]

Question 2 reference:

[image]

Question 3 reference:

[image]

Breville 800-esxl espresso machine repair, circuit repair.

Comment: If they provided class II isolation between everything connected to it and any user accessible parts? Then it’s allowed.

Comment: I guess my question is more along the lines of how it functions, I don't understand how they use 120VAC as the reference and the circuit works, I'm mostly looking for some circuit expertise.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking the potential hazards (pun intended), stumped you. Is it Italian by any chance? I’ve seen this scheme in Italian made HVAC controls too.

Comment: Tip: you have tagged this as 'virtual ground' but if you hover over the tag you'll see that the term means something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voltage is relative. When you're working with a circuit, you can choose any point you want as the reference point, and measure and describe all your voltages relative to that point.

The designers of this circuit have decided to use the AC hot conductor as their reference point. As a result:

- The AC hot conductor has a voltage of 0 V at all times (because it's the reference point).
- The AC neutral conductor has a voltage of 120 V AC.
- The anodes of ZD1 and ZD6 are both connected to a point that has a voltage of 0 V. The reason for that is that they are connected to the AC hot conductor, and the AC hot conductor has a voltage of 0 V.
- If ZD6 has a Zener voltage of 24 V, and it's conducting in reverse, then the voltage at its cathode is 24 V higher than the voltage at its anode. Since the voltage at its anode is 0 V, the voltage at its cathode will be 24 V.

While you're analyzing this circuit yourself, you also have to pick a reference point. You have two reasonable options:

- Use the AC hot conductor as your reference point, just like the circuit designers did. This will make the analysis relatively easy.
- Use the AC neutral conductor, or the earth, as your reference point. This will make the analysis very difficult and confusing, so don't do this!

Answer (score 2):

> Using AC Line as DC Neutral Reference for Microprocessor.

Your title is incorrect or confused. The DC ground is connected to mains AC live.

> 1. How do they use AC 120VAC as the micro ground?

See the GND connection on the 'L' mains pin.

> How do they use 120 VAC reference as the reference for the Zener diodes ZD6 (24V Zener), ZD1 (5 V Zener) whilst the Zener diodes still function in their reversed bias direction?

The power supply is a capacitive voltage dropper. R1A and B are there to discharge the capacitor when the device is unplugged. D1 prevents the right hand side of C1 going negative on negative-going half-cycles. D2 conducts on positive-going half-cycles to pass charge into C2.

> How is ZD6 able to keep the voltage at 24VDC given that it appears to have no resistors between it and power supplied through D1 & D2 and that it has full 120VAC as it's reference?

C1 limits the current. 1.5 μF has an impedance of 2 kΩ at 50 Hz. (See [All About Circuits calculator](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/capacitor-impedance-calculator/).) 2 kΩ will limit current to \$ \frac {120}{2000} = 60 \ \mathrm {mA} \$.

Answer (score 1):

Study this: -

[image]

> *How is ZD6 able to keep the voltage at 24 VDC given that it appears to
> have no resistors between it and power supplied through D1 & D2 and
> that it has full 120 VAC as it's reference?*

The impedance of the "volt-dropping capacitor" at 60 Hz is 1768 Ω. So, it acts like an impedance to prevent the zener diodes getting too much current.

> *How do they use 120 VAC reference as the reference for the zener
> diodes ZD6 (24 V Zener), ZD1 (5 V Zener) whilst the zener diodes still
> function in their reversed bias direction?*

D1 & D2 rectify the remaining AC voltage and C2 smooths it. It then feeds the Zeners and hence, the Zeners are always in their normal reverse biased "voltage regulating" state.

> *How do they use 120 VAC as the micro ground?*

It's not pretty but it does work. It's an un-isolated (aka dangerous in the wrong hands) AC to DC power supply that avoids the cost of using a transformer.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses, it does make sense to me.  I hadn't considered that capacitor resistance varies with frequency as well.  It took a bit to consider that micros can float their DC on an AC circuit as well. 
Thanks for walking me through this, lots of thoughtful and informative and answers.